# Jedis benchmarking on local Redis server

Tags: redis, benchmarking, connection-pooling, jedis, jmh

I'm using JMH to test the performance of Jedis on a local Redis server (Jedis version 2.9.0, Redis version 6.2.6, CPU Quad-Core Intel Core i5). I use 200 threads to send `SET` command within a connection pool.

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class CommonClientBenchmark {

    private JedisPool jedisPool;
    private final String host = "127.0.0.1";
    private final int port = 6379;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(200);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(200);
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, host, port, 30000);
    }

    @TearDown
    public void tearDown() {
        jedisPool.close();
    }

    @Threads(200)
    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    @Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 30, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 2, time = 30, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void jedisSet() {
        try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
            jedis.set("jedis", "jedis");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, RunnerException {
        CommonClientBenchmark commonClientBenchmark = new CommonClientBenchmark();
        commonClientBenchmark.setup();
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

With the code above, I obtain about 25000+ QPS. However, when I decrease the `maxTotal` and `maxIdle` parameter of the connection pool from 200 to 100, the result QPS is even much higher - it reaches about 75000. Could anyone explain the phenomenon? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** I've change the version of Jedis to 4.1.1 and run multiple benchmarking tests, the result is similar. When the size of connection pool is set to 100 (both `maxTotal` and `maxIdle`), I obtain about 25000 ~ 50000 QPS. When I increase the size (both `maxTotal` and `maxIdle`) to 200, the QPS rise to 60000 ~ 75000.

I've also use `iostat 1` to monitor the usage of CPU while running the tests. And I found that when the pool size is set to 200, the *%system* is often much higher than when it is set to 100.

connection pool size set to 200:

```
              disk0       cpu    load average
    KB/t  tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
    4.09  929  3.71   7 87  6  39.58 14.44 8.06
    4.00  902  3.52   6 89  5  39.58 14.44 8.06
    4.50    8  0.04   5 88  6  38.33 14.60 8.15
    4.39  145  0.62   6 89  6  38.33 14.60 8.15
   28.00   11  0.30   6 88  5  38.33 14.60 8.15
    8.00    1  0.01   5 88  6  38.33 14.60 8.15
    0.00    0  0.00   5 88  7  38.33 14.60 8.15
    4.00    5  0.02   5 88  7  38.94 15.12 8.37
    0.00    0  0.00   5 89  6  38.94 15.12 8.37
    0.00    0  0.00   5 88  7  38.94 15.12 8.37
    0.00    0  0.00   5 89  6  38.94 15.12 8.37
    8.68  222  1.88   5 88  7  38.94 15.12 8.37
    5.60   10  0.05   5 87  8  45.20 16.81 9.01
   29.65   46  1.33  11 82  7  45.20 16.81 9.01
   52.57    7  0.36   8 85  7  45.20 16.81 9.01
   28.00    2  0.05   5 87  8  45.20 16.81 9.01
  223.33    6  1.31   6 87  7  45.20 16.81 9.01
    4.19 1344  5.49   8 85  7  44.54 17.15 9.17
    4.61  952  4.29   6 89  5  44.54 17.15 9.17
    4.00  690  2.69   6 89  5  44.54 17.15 9.17
```

connection pool size set to 100:

```
              disk0       cpu    load average
    KB/t  tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
    4.31   13  0.05  16 59 26  6.55 7.86 7.49
  750.67    3  2.20  30 53 17  6.58 7.85 7.48
    9.14  225  2.01  23 54 23  6.58 7.85 7.48
   37.00    8  0.29  23 56 21  6.58 7.85 7.48
   32.00    6  0.19  18 55 26  6.58 7.85 7.48
  145.20   10  1.41  22 56 22  6.58 7.85 7.48
    0.00    0  0.00  22 56 22  6.46 7.80 7.47
    4.00 2660 10.39  24 58 18  6.46 7.80 7.47
    4.00 1952  7.62  19 56 25  6.46 7.80 7.47
    4.00    1  0.00  19 56 24  6.46 7.80 7.47
    4.00    5  0.02  18 56 27  6.46 7.80 7.47
    0.00    0  0.00  15 57 28  6.10 7.71 7.44
    0.00    0  0.00  18 57 25  6.10 7.71 7.44
  256.00   10  2.50  18 56 25  6.10 7.71 7.44
    6.29    7  0.04  20 57 23  6.10 7.71 7.44
    4.00    5  0.02  20 56 24  6.10 7.71 7.44
   17.71    7  0.12  20 56 24  6.01 7.66 7.42
   23.00    4  0.09  20 58 23  6.01 7.66 7.42
    5.00    4  0.02  23 55 22  6.01 7.66 7.42
    4.00    1  0.00  20 56 24  6.01 7.66 7.42
```

Comment: Which Jedis version are you using?

Comment: @sazzad the version of Jedis is 2.9.0